# Checking if a Stack is an arithmetic series | Java

Tags: java, stack

I'm trying to check if a stack is also an arithmetic series (has arithmetic progression). I can't figure out why I'm getting a null error here. The error points at "diff".

```
public static boolean isArithmetic(Stack<Integer> s) {

    if (s == null)
        return true;

    int diff = s.pop() - s.peek(); // Get difference

    while (!s.isEmpty()) {
        int x = s.pop(); 

        if ((s.peek() == null))
            return true;
        if (x - s.peek() != diff) 
            return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: All assignments to `int` without null check could throw `NPE` f your stack has `null` elements. Like this line `int diff = s.pop() - s.peek(); ` and in this line `int x = s.pop();`

Comment: Thanks, I added a null check to every one of the lines you mentioned, and it's working well.

Answer (score 0):

[The javadoc for peek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#peek()) should help you understand why this is throwing:

"Throws EmptyStackException - if this stack is empty."

Consider changing the test from `s.peek() == null` to `s.isEmpty()`!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since the [`java.util.Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class is actually a [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), you can easily do that without modifying the stack.

```
public static boolean isArithmetic(Stack<Integer> s) {
    if (s.size() <= 1)
        return false; // or true?
    int diff = s.get(1) - s.get(0);
    for (int i = 2; i < s.size(); i++)
        if (s.get(i) - s.get(i - 1) != diff)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```